# Configuring tab space for Eclipse Compare Merge editor

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff

Is there a way to configure tab spaces for Eclipse Compare/Merge editor?

I have the Text Editor to use 2 spaces for tab and "Insert spaces for tabs" but this doesn't seem to take effect in the Compare/Merge editor. It's quite annoying since it's occasionally messing up the indentation in the source code. I guess my other option is to use an external tool but it would be great if this can be configured within Eclipse.

I'm using Indigo SR2 (64-bit)

--
This appears to be a related Eclipse bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=259410

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to ignore whitespaces in the compare editor. Either you right click in the editor and choose `Ignore White Space` or you set this in eclipses preferences `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Compare/Patch` -> `Ignore White Space`

Comment: Thanks, I know I can ignore whitespaces. Sometimes, one of the developer actually edits when in Compare/Merge editor and it really messes up the indentation since there is no way to change tab spacing.